# Sphinx giving me same result after modyfing field

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Removing some data from a field, let say this field contain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and I'm
removing '3' (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9) and manually run the delta indexer and search for '3' but
very sadly this field also showing which have not '3', with the others with '3'

I run the main indexer (indexer --rotate --all) but the result remain same.

Any suggestion most welcome.